# Unable to import com.google.android.maps.MapView (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android

```
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class MapView extends MapActivity {
      LinearLayout linearLayout;
      MapView mapView;

      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.map);
          mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
          mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
          MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i jus realised that i would have to install the google api to fix my problem

Answer (score 1):

at first glance you have name conflict between Google MapView and your MapView class. Just rename your class to MyMapView

Comment: it is a good practice to let your IDE write imports for you. If it doesn't than it is an environment problem.

Comment: +1 - This may not be the cause of the SO's compilation error, but he is going to have to fix it anyway.